# Passing an HTML Element into a Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parameters

I know this has been answered, but it seems that none of the questions are relevant to exactly my point.. My code is below. I need to pass in either the variable `$dynamicPanel` in to the second function, or pass `this` in to the second function. Either way would be acceptable.

While we're at it, is there any way that I can wait some number of seconds to execute the `FirstAnimation` function without again using the `animate()` method.

```
$(document).ready(function FirstAnimation() {
    var $dynamicPanel = $(".dynamicPanel");
    $('.dynamicPanel').animate({
        opacity: 0,
        left: '100'
    }, 5000, function () {
        alert('first animation complete');
        SecondAnimation(this);
    });
});

function SecondAnimation(this) {
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 100, function () {
        alert('second animation complete');
        FirstAnimation();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is a reserved word and can't be used as a parameter name. You should do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   FirstAnimation();
});

function FirstAnimation() {
   //this function doesn't change, use your code
};

function SecondAnimation(elem) {         
    $(elem).animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 100, function () {
        alert('second animation complete');
        setTimeout(function(){  //Delay FirstAnimation 7 seconds
           FirstAnimation();
        }, 7000);
    });    
};
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

What about changing `SecondAnimation(this);` to `SecondAnimation($dynamicPanel);`? It looks like it would do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

this waiting can be done with **[jQuery.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)**

```
$(document).ready(function FirstAnimation() {
    var $dynamicPanel = $(".dynamicPanel");
    $dynamicPanel.animate({
        opacity: 0,
        left: '100'
    }, 5000, function () {
        alert('first animation complete');
        SecondAnimation($dynamicPanel); // <--pass the proper variable ;)
    });
});

function SecondAnimation(this) {
    $(this).delay(5000).animate({ //<<-- wait five seconds
        opacity: 1
    }, 100, function () {
        alert('second animation complete');
        FirstAnimation();
    });
};
```

however you can call the whole function **recursive** and pass the **animation settings as paramaters from an array**. So you **reuse** the function and *only change the behaviour*.

```
 // store animationsettings in an array;
 var animationSettings = [{opacity: 0, left: '100'},{  opacity: 1 }];   
 // initialize the startup index
 var x = 1;   
 // cache selector
 var $dynamicPanel  =  $(".dynamicPanel");
 // single function
 (function animate(){
     x = x == 1 ? 0 : 1;//<--- toggle the index
     $dynamicPanel.delay(x * 5000).animate(animationSettings[x], 
        1000, 
        function () {
           animate(); // recursive call this function.
        });
 }());
```

**[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fEde8/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use `SecondAnimation.apply(this)`.